# How to reuse a Random seed in Java so that I nextInt() the same values again?

Tags: java, random

I first call my `randomGenerator` object as such:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random(5);
for (int i = 0; i < intObjects.length; i++){
    intObjects[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Now if I wanted to re-initialize my array (after making some changes to it and doing some tests) with the SAME original randomly generated values, how would I do so? How do I reuse the seed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random(5);
```

The new Random(5); is how you seeded your generator. If you resuse this, you will get the same numbers as before.

```
randomGenerator = new Random(5);
```

is the solution. (A new object is not needed)

Comment: "A new object is not needed" is right, but you created one. You can just use `randomGenerator.setSeed(5)` if you want to re-use the same object.

Comment: Right. It is a new instance of Random() but is assigned to "old" randomGenerator =). The setSeed() function is much nicer, i have forget this one.

Answer (score 2):

Fix the seed, that's it.

```
  Random randomGenerator = new Random(5);
  System.out.println(randomGenerator.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
  randomGenerator = new Random(5);
  System.out.println(randomGenerator.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
  randomGenerator = new Random(5);
  System.out.println(randomGenerator.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
  randomGenerator = new Random(5);
  System.out.println(randomGenerator.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

Result :

1568779487

1568779487

1568779487

1568779487

Answer (score 1):

The seed, in your code is the long passed as argument to the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) : `5`.

So each time you'll run that, you'll get the same values.

Comment: I guess I was confused whether I could reuse the object or not. I was trying to use `randomGenerator` again but couldn't figure out how and it wasn't really compiling. Now I just made a new object with the same seed and yeah it works. Confirm that I can't reuse the same object?

Comment: That's the normal way.

Comment: ohhhhhh, ok I was a little confused. didnt think i could make a new Random(5) on an object that already been initialized but that makes sense. understood from 2nd answer

Answer (score 0):

You just have to store your seed and init your random generator a new time. Take a look in at this code:

```
    // Generate one uniq seed
    long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Create your random with the seed
    Random randomGenerator = new Random(seed);

    // Use it
    for (int i = 0; i < intObjects.length; ++i) {
        intObjects[i]=randomGenerator.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
    }

    // Do what you want
    // ...

    // Regenerate your random
    randomGenerator = new Random(seed); // Maybe you can also use randomGenerator.setSeed(seed)        

    // Use it again
    for (int i = 0; i < intObjects.length; ++i) {
        intObjects[i]=randomGenerator.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
    }
```